# Ember.js update model attribute

Tags: ember.js

I do not have the best understanding of how ember.js works. I am currently working on updating an attribute called features (an array of strings) that each owner has using a multi select checkbox. So far everything seems to be working except for the updated features attribute is not saving. When I click the checkbox it updates the selected computed property in the multi-select-checkboxes component. I thought if I was passing model.owner.features as selected to the component it would directly update the model when the component changes.

```
(function() {
  const { shroud } = Sw.Lib.Decorators;

  Sw.FranchisorNewAnalyticsConnectionsUsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    currentFranchisorService: Ember.inject.service('currentFranchisor'),

    @shroud
    model({ account_id }) {
      console.log("load model in route")
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        account: this.get('store').find('account', account_id),
        owners: Sw.AccountOwner.fetch(account_id),
        newAccountOwner: Sw.AccountOwner.NewAccountOwner.create({ accountID: account_id }),
      });
    },

    actions: {
      @shroud
      accountOwnersChanged() {
        this.refresh();
      },

      close() {
        this.transitionTo('franchisor.newAnalytics.connections');
      },
    },
  });
})();
```

users controller:

```
(function() {
  const { shroud, on, observer } = Sw.Lib.Decorators;
  Sw.FranchisorNewAnalyticsConnectionsUsersController = Ember.Controller.extend(Sw.FranchisorControllerMixin, {
    isAddingUser: false,

    adminOptions: [{
      label: 'Employee Advocacy',
      value: 'employee advocacy'
    }, {
      label: 'Second Feature',
      value: 'other'
    }, {
      label: 'Can edit users?',
      value: 'edit_users'
    }],

  });
})();
```

users.handlebars

```
 {{#each model.owners as |owner|}}
   <tr
    <td>
     {{owner.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
     {{owner.email}}
    </td>
    <td>{{if owner.confirmedAt 'Yes' 'No'}}</td>
    <td>
      {{log 'owner.features' owner.features}}
      {{multi-select-checkboxes 
         options=adminOptions 
         selected=owner.features
         owner=owner
         model=model
       }}
     </td>
     <td>
       <button class="btn light-red-button" 
         {{action "remove" owner}}>
         Remove
       </button>
     </td>
   </tr>
 {{/each}}
```

multi-select-checkboxes.handlebar:

```
{{#each checkboxes as |checkbox|}}
  <p>
    <label>
      {{input type='checkbox' checked=checkbox.isChecked}}
      {{checkbox.label}}
    </label>
  </p>
{{/each}}
```

multi_select_checkboxes.jsx:

```
 // Each available option becomes an instance of a "MultiSelectCheckbox" object.
var MultiSelectCheckbox = Ember.Object.extend({
  label: 'label',
  value: 'value',
  isChecked: false,

  changeValue: function () { },
  onIsCheckedChanged: Ember.observer('isChecked', function () {
    var fn = (this.get('isChecked') === true) ? 'pushObject' : 'removeObject';
    this.get('changeValue').call(this, fn, this.get('value'));
  })
});

Sw.MultiSelectCheckboxesComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  labelProperty: 'label',
  valueProperty: 'value',
  // The list of available options.
  options: [],
  // The collection of selected options. This should be a property on
  // a model. It should be a simple array of strings.
  selected: [],
  owner: null,
  model: null,
  checkboxes: Ember.computed('options', function () {
      console.log("CHECKBOXES", this.get('model'))
    var _this = this;
    var labelProperty = this.get('labelProperty');
    var valueProperty = this.get('valueProperty');
    var selected = this.get('selected'); 
    var model = this.get('model'); 
    return this.get('options').map(function (opt) {
      var label = opt[labelProperty];
      var value = opt[valueProperty];
      var isChecked = selected.contains(value);
      return MultiSelectCheckbox.create({
        label: label,
        value: value,
        isChecked: isChecked,
        model: model,
        changeValue: function (fn, value, model) {
          _this.get('selected')[fn](value);
          console.log("model in middle", this.get('model'))
          this.get('model').save();
        }
      });
    });
  }),
  actions: {
    amountChanged() {
      const model = this.get(this, 'model');
      this.sendAction('amountChanged', model); 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I’d expect a call to `save` a record at some point if you want the changes to be persisted via the API, maybe in the `changeValue` handler?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what version of ember are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a pretty decent understanding to me! I think your implementation is just missing a thing here or there and might be a tad more complex than it has to be.

Here's a [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/70ffc05804f7404d13a8584615f45e9f?openFiles=components.multi-select-checkbox.js%2Ctemplates.components.multi-select-checkbox.hbs) that does what you're asking for. I named the property on the model `attrs` to avoid possible confusion as `attributes` comes into play with some model methods such as `rollbackAttributes()` or `changedAttributes()`.

Some things to note:

1. You don't need to specify a `changeValue` function when creating your list of checkbox objects. The `onIsCheckedChanged` observer should be responsible for updating the model's attribute. Just pass the model or its attribute you want to update (the array of strings) into each checkbox during the mapping of the `options` in the multi select checkbox:

```
return Checkbox.create({
  label: option.label,
  value: option.value,
  attributes: this.get('owner.attrs') // this array will be updated by the Checkbox
});
```

2. If the model you retrieve doesn't have any data in this array, Ember Data will leave the attribute as `undefined` so doing an update directly on the array will cause an error (e.g., `cannot read property 'pushObject' of undefined`) so be sure the property is set to an array before this component lets a user update the value.
3. The observer will fire [synchronously](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/observers/#toc_observers-and-asynchrony) so it might be worthwhile to wrap it in a [Ember.run.once()](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.11/classes/@ember%2Frunloop/methods/once?anchor=once) (not sure what else you will be doing with this component / model so I note this for completeness).
4. If you want to save the changes on the model automatically you'll need to call `.save()` on the model after making the update. In this case I would pass the model in to each checkbox and call save after making the change.

Comment: So if I pass the model into the component I can do model.save() in the component or does this have to happen in the controller?

Comment: @Kris yes, you can call `model.save()` in the component if you pass the model into it.

Comment: When I try that .save() shows up as undefined, do I have to add a save action?

Comment: @Kris make sure you're passing the full model and not just the `features` attribute. If you're passing the full `owner` model into the component you will be able to call save.

Comment: So i passed model as model=model into the component and then in changeValue function I added this.get('model').save(); at the end but is still shows .save() as undefined.

Comment: @Kris can you update the code snippets in your question? Also be sure you pass the model not just into the multi select checkbox but to the individual checkboxes as well as that's where the features array will be changed.

Comment: @Kris thanks! the reason it's coming up `undefined` in the `changeValue` function is because you're doing `this.get('model')` in a different context (the function you're calling `changeValue`). I don't think you need the `changeValue` function but if you want to use it, then just reference the model variable you already created above and call `model.save()`

Comment: @Kris in my opinion I'd rather do:

```
onIsCheckedChanged: Ember.observer('isChecked', function () {
  // still need to add the code for whether to push or remove
  this.get('model.features').pushObject(this.get('value'));
  this.get('model').save();
})
```